# Use wireshark to measure Sybase DB Execution times

Tags: timestamp, odbc, wireshark

I am trying to isolate the amount of time it takes to execute a series of SQL queries on Sybase DB. I have captured a tcpdump. When I open this tcpdump file in wireshark, I follow TCP stream. 
How to calculate the actual SQL execution time from this TCP stream?

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really can with a wireshark log.  The closest you can get to that is the amount of time that elapses between the TCP packet arriving at the sever and when a response went back to the client.  There will be some time that elapses between the TCP packets arrival and the SQL command making its way to the DB.  SQL Server has tools built in to it that well show you execution time of command.  I don't know that Sybase does but that is the direction I would be looking.